# Slide images automatically and manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

for an image slider I use this code

```js
var sliderIndex = 0;

function initializeImageSlider() {
    var sliderImages = $(".sliderImg");

    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    sliderIndex++;
    if (sliderIndex > sliderImages.length) {
        sliderIndex = 1;
    }
    sliderImages[sliderIndex-1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(initializeImageSlider, 5000);
}

function changeSliderImage(direction) {
    sliderIndex += direction;
    alert("move " + direction);
}
```

```css
#containerImageSlider {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.sliderImg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onLoad="initializeImageSlider()">

<button onclick="changeSliderImage(-1)">-</button>
<div id="containerImageSlider">
    <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/sliderImg1.png">
    <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/sliderImg2.png">
    <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/sliderImg3.png">
    <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/sliderImg4.png">
    <img class="sliderImg" src="Resources/sliderImg5.png">
</div>
<button onclick="changeSliderImage(1)">+</button>

</body>
```

So the automatic slider works fine. Now I added two buttons, they call the function `changeSliderImage(direction)` where I pass in a value for moving forwards or backwards.

As you can see, currently I just use the `initializeImageSlider()` function to have an automatic slider.

How can I create a function, to have this automatic and manual process working?

I don't get, how to split my `initializeImageSlider()` function for this.

Comment: here is a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pigarilugo/edit?html,output) that will do exactly, if you want i will add it as answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function `updateImageSlider()` that only updates the slider, whether the `sliderIndex` increases or decreases. Then you simply call this method each time the countdown reaches 5s or when the user clicks on the buttons.

This code should do what you want:

```
var sliderIndex = 0;

function updateImageSlider() {
    var sliderImages = $(".sliderImg");

    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
        sliderImages[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    if (sliderIndex > sliderImages.length) {
        sliderIndex = 1;
    }
    else if (sliderIndex < 1) {
        sliderIndex = sliderImages.length;
    }
    sliderImages[sliderIndex-1].style.display = "block";
}

var autoSlideHandler; // To reset the timer
function incrementImageSlider() {
    sliderIndex++;
    updateImageSlider();
    autoSlideHandler = setTimeout(incrementImageSlider, 5000);
}

function changeSliderImage(direction) {
    // Move the slider
    sliderIndex += direction;
    updateImageSlider();
    alert("move " + direction);
    // Reset the timer
    clearTimeout(autoSlideHandler);
    autoSlideHandler = setTimeout(incrementImageSlider, 5000);
}

$(incrementImageSlider); // Initialize the slider, function called on page load
```